# Java labels crossing each other

Tags: label

Is there any way to put JLabels one top on other? Trying to make a card hand representation in Netbeans. I am using JLabel icon for each card. Like you have 1st card (label) on top, then next one a bit right and down from the 1st card and etc. Netbeans form designer does not allow to make intersections of JLabels. Just put the label next to another one.

Comment: For the future provide the code you have for better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in JLayeredPane